# Django Custom User Error: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Tags: python, django

I'm following the Django document [Customer user and proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/) to create a custom user model.

The code is exactly same, I just copy the while brunch of the code into my project. But it's showing up an error.

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

Error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lst3J.png)

I have no idea how to fix this error.

*In customers/models.py: *

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, date_of_birth, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, date_of_birth, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['date_of_birth']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```

*In customers/admin.py: *

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('email', 'date_of_birth')

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'date_of_birth', 'is_active', 'is_admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        return self.initial["password"]


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):

    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    list_display = ('email', 'date_of_birth', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('date_of_birth',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'date_of_birth', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()


admin.site.register(MyUser, UserAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

*In settings.py: *

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'customers.MyUser'
```

Comment: Add [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I've added code, can you please have a look?

Comment: You can inherit `django.contrib.auth.models.PermissionsMixin` in your user model, instead of writing this permission methods and fields (is_admin, is_active, has_perm etc.). For the error you get, I believe that is because you made the initial migrations and then created your custom User model. Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project). The simplest solution would be drop the whole database, and remove all migration files and then make the migrations from scratch.

Comment: hi @fxgx but what if I want to separate the super users and the normal users into two tables but sharing the same model. What can I do to achieve this goal?